# Working with a geometry that spans 4 orders of magnitude

Tags: geometry

I have to work with a geometry described by:

```
slab = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {7, 7, 0.3*10^-4}];
```

describing an electrode 7 cm wide and 0.3 micrometers thick. The problem is that Mathematica uses up all the memory while defining the geometry and the kernel crashes: is there a work around?

If needed I use version 11.3 for windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that Mathematica uses up all the memory while defining the geometry and the kernel crashes"? Maybe you describe what happens when you evaluate `DiscretizeRegion[slab]`?

Comment: It means what I wrote: when evaluating the cell with the definition of `slab`, the use of the RAM spikes and the kernel crashes.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't change units (i.e. rescale)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior in version 11.3 for macOS.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I tried to rescale using micrometers as unit (so the cuboid has dimension 7000 X 7000 X 0.3), but the same thing happens

Comment: I can not reproduce this on Linux either, what OS do you have and what version do you use? Have you tried exact values: `slab = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {7, 7, 3/10*10^-4}];`?

Comment: @user21 as I wrote, I use version 11.3 for windows.

Comment: @user21 with your modification the program works. Thank you!

Comment: deleted my previous comment, as I can no longer reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try exact coordinates:

```
slab = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {7, 7, 3/10*10^-4}]
```

Comment: @mattiav27This may serve as temporary work-around, but in the end you should report the issue to Wolfram Support so that it can be fixed in future version.